# Variable comparison error using firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, kotlin, authentication

**Why is the res variable always false even though the parameters are correct?**

```
    fun isValidUser(_studentEmail: String, _password: String): Boolean {
        var res = false

        userList.get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for (document in result) {
                val studentEmail = document.data["studentEmail"] as String
                val password = document.data["password"] as String

                if (_studentEmail == studentEmail && _password == password) {
                    res = true
                }
            }
        }
        return res
    }
```

Comment: There is no way you can do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So I think that you might be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't behave like you think it does.

The `userList.get()` launches an *asynchronous* task, which means the program will continue its execution without waiting for the task to be done.

`addOnSuccessListener` only registers a listener - a piece of code to run when the query successfully completes, but that piece of code will only be run in the future, not right away, because the query takes some time.

When the program reaches the `return res`, the query still hasn't completed and the listener hasn't been executed yet.

If you want to reason more sequentially about this stuff, you can use Kotlin coroutine extensions to `await()` the result instead of registering a listener. Check out [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/README.md) for instance. However, if you have trouble understanding asynchronous behaviour, you should probably read up more about this before diving into coroutines.